# Failed Install Diagnostics

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office

I've downloaded office 2010. But when trying to install a pop-up comes up asking for my permission, and as I soon as I click ok, I see a progress bar for about .8 of a second, and then that's it.

No install, no messages, no help at all. Where does Windows 7 keep a log of why things failed etc?

Maybe I can run the installer in a different mode?

Comment: Do you have full permissions? What if you try running this as administrator?

Answer (score 1):

Use Event Viewer by either typing 'Event Viewer' in the start menu or by running `eventvwr.exe`. The logs are in `Windows Logs\Setup`.